# Steps toward making the Feynman integral rigorous

Tags: definition, mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory

I would like to know if there has been any progress recently toward giving the Feynman integral a rigorous definition. I heard that Richard Borcherds is working on giving quantum field theory a rigorous foundation, but I am not familiar with his work. Perhaps someone here on the M.S.E. who is familiar with what he does can give some insight?

Comment: This was asked on mathoverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/24823/the-mathematical-theory-of-feynman-integrals